# Re-using interfaces for dynamic methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a module that wraps all methods of a library to make them chainable, so instead of:

```
const result = lib.three(lib.two(lib.one('abc')))
```

The user will be able to do this:

```
const result = new Chainable('abc').one().two().three().value
```

To do this my code, a class, wraps each method:

```js
import lib from 'lib'

class Chainable {
  public value: any

  constructor (value: any) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

const methods = Object.keys(lib)

for (const method of methods) {
  Chainable.prototype[method] = function (this: Chainable) {
    this.value = Reflect.apply(lib[method], null, [ this.value, ...arguments ])
    return this
  }
}

export default Chainable
```

It would be great if all of library methods, and their signatures could be inferred. Is it possible to *extend* or re-use in any way the typings from the underlying library?

Comment: Does the library take other arguments to the methods or are they all `(v: T)=> T ` ?

Comment: Most methods accept only a string, but a few do accept am optional second argument for options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I like this question, but I think TypeScript isn't quite ready to solve it in a satisfying way.  The main problem is that given the type of `lib`, you'd *like to* programmatically pull the types of arguments and return values out of its methods, and then transform those to produce the types of methods of `Chainable`. That won't really be feasible until [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and their associated [type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) abilities become part of the language, which *looks* like it'll be around TypeScript v2.8.

---

For now, this is as close as I can get. First, describe a `LibTemplate` to represent function signatures in a way that you can transform programmatically:

```
type LibTemplate = {[k: string]: { arg: any, ret: any }}

type LibFunc<L extends LibTemplate> = {
  [K in keyof L]: (arg: L[K]['arg']) => L[K]['ret']
}
```

So your `lib` will be a `LibFunc<Lib>` for some type `Lib`.  Here's an example:

```
declare const lib: {
  one(arg: string): number;
  two(arg: number): boolean;
  three(arg: boolean): string;
}
```

where

```
type Lib = {
  one: {arg: string, ret: number},
  two: {arg: number, ret: boolean},
  three: {arg: boolean, ret: string}
}
```

You can verify yourself that `LibFunc<Lib>` has the same shape as `typeof lib`.  Unfortunately TypeScript is not good at inferring `Lib` from `typeof lib`, and won't be until something like conditional types is available.  So below I'm going to have to explicitly use `Lib`.

Please note that I'm not even trying to deal with functions with more than one argument.  I might consider looking at that if this answer goes anywhere, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth at the moment.

Let's just examine the "normal" use of the library:

```
const plainResult = lib.three(lib.two(lib.one("abc"))); // string
```

Now I'm going to describe the types necessary to represent converting `lib` into a `Chainable` class.  The implementation is not my concern here, but the types seen by the user of the library.

```
type Chainable<L extends LibTemplate, V extends L[keyof L]['arg' | 'ret']> = {
  value: V
} & {
    [K in keyof L]: (this: Chainable<L, L[K]['arg']>) => Chainable<L, L[K]['ret']>
}
```

So a `Chainable` takes two type arguments.  The `L` argument represents the shape of the library, and the `V` argument represents the type of the currently-represented `value`.  The `V` type must be one of either the arguments or return values of one of the library function.

Each `Chainable<L,V>` has a `value` of type `V`, as well as a set of no-arg methods for each key in `L`, of a type that requires that the current `V` matches the argument type of the library function... and they return a `Chainable<L,V>` with a new value of `V`.

Finally here's the function signature for converting a `lib` into a `Chainable` constructor:

```
declare function chainify<L extends LibTemplate>(
  lib: LibFunc<L>
): {new <V extends L[keyof L]['arg'|'ret']>(value: V): Chainable<Lib, V>}
```

Here's where we call it.  Note how I have to specify `Lib` as the type parameter, due to the aforementioned inference issue:

```
const ChainableLib = chainify<Lib>(lib);
```

Let's try to use it...

```
const chainResult = new ChainableLib("abc").one().two().three().value; // string
```

It works!  And you get some type safety:

```
new ChainableLib(null); // error, not string | number | boolean
new ChainableLib(true).one() // error, true is not a string
new ChainableLib(true).two() // error, true is not a number
new ChainableLib(true).three() // this one is okay
```

(view this code in [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20LibTemplate%20%3D%20%7B%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20arg%3A%20any%2C%20ret%3A%20any%20%7D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20LibFunc%3CL%20extends%20LibTemplate%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20L%5D%3A%20%28arg%3A%20L%5BK%5D%5B%27arg%27%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20L%5BK%5D%5B%27ret%27%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20lib%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20one%28arg%3A%20string%29%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20two%28arg%3A%20number%29%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20three%28arg%3A%20boolean%29%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Lib%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20one%3A%20%7Barg%3A%20string%2C%20ret%3A%20number%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20two%3A%20%7Barg%3A%20number%2C%20ret%3A%20boolean%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20three%3A%20%7Barg%3A%20boolean%2C%20ret%3A%20string%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20plainResult%20%3D%20lib.three%28lib.two%28lib.one%28%22abc%22%29%29%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Chainable%3CL%20extends%20LibTemplate%2C%20V%20extends%20L%5Bkeyof%20L%5D%5B%27arg%27%20%7C%20%27ret%27%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20V%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20L%5D%3A%20%28this%3A%20Chainable%3CL%2C%20L%5BK%5D%5B%27arg%27%5D%3E%29%20%3D%3E%20Chainable%3CL%2C%20L%5BK%5D%5B%27ret%27%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20chainify%3CL%20extends%20LibTemplate%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20lib%3A%20LibFunc%3CL%3E%0D%0A%29%3A%20%7Bnew%20%3CV%20extends%20L%5Bkeyof%20L%5D%5B%27arg%27%7C%27ret%27%5D%3E%28value%3A%20V%29%3A%20Chainable%3CLib%2C%20V%3E%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ChainableLib%20%3D%20chainify%3CLib%3E%28lib%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20chainResult%20%3D%20new%20ChainableLib%28%22abc%22%29.one%28%29.two%28%29.three%28%29.value%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20safety%0D%0Anew%20ChainableLib%28null%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20not%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0Anew%20ChainableLib%28true%29.one%28%29%20%2F%2F%20true%20is%20not%20a%20string%0D%0Anew%20ChainableLib%28true%29.two%28%29%20%2F%2F%20true%20is%20not%20a%20number%0D%0Anew%20ChainableLib%28true%29.three%28%29%20%2F%2F%20okay))

---

Ugh, that is messy.  I'm not sure if someone else has a cleaner solution.  But that's the best I can do for now.  Hope it's helpful; good luck!

Comment: Wow, what an epic answer! I'll digest it and get back =]

Comment: Wow, really cool answer, I missed the inference part of conditional types. I got stuck on inferring `lib` and decided it wouldn't be worth it. Definitely worth an update once 2.8 rolls around ;)